# Detect change of option values of an select field using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle-apex, jquery-events

Is there a way of event binding to recognize when the options of a select field get changed by some different, external, not editable JavaScript?

Just to clearify: I don't want to listen to value changes, I want to listen to a change of the DOM structure

Comment: Is the whole element being replaced? Need a bit more detail on exactly what is getting modified and show some structure

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: So is there any reason you have tagged this with Oracle Apex? Since you're talking select list options, would this be a list which is being refreshed somehow (eg: cascading list)? Can you please provide some more information on your actual problem instead of a problematic solution?

Comment: @Tom: Yes, the basis of my list is a select list with cascading LOV. My use case is quite complicated, basically my LOV Cascading select list is based on some text fields. When they get changed my select list changes and I want to perform some action as soon as the reload of the select list is finished.

Comment: Just to doubly verify: you have a select list, and the 'cascading lov parent items' are set to those text items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this?

This will only tell you if there is any change to the structure.

```js
$(".selectBox").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() 
{
    $(".message").append("Structure changed<br>");
});


$("#add").click(function() 
{
    $(".selectBox").append("<option>Added</option>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="add">Add to Select</button>


<select class="selectBox">


</select>


<div class="message"></div>
```

If you was looking for anything like data or attributes. Then you will probably be looking for something like [**`MutationObserver`**](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

> MutationObserver provides developers a way to react to changes in a DOM. It is designed as a replacement for Mutation Events defined in the DOM3 Events specification.

Comment: did you read the question thoroughly? OP clearly states they don't need to listen for `change`

Comment: the downvote was for previous answer that was completely wrong and therefore of little value. That should not have been a mystery. removed based on updated answer however should mention browser support as well as potential for infinitie loop this event can create

Comment: Did not see any previous answer, but this one solved it for me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Looking for "DOM Changes" is cutting it way too broad. As your comment has pointed out, you are using the cascading LOV parent items functionality on your select list. This turns the select list into a refreshable item which means it will get its set of options again when one of those parent items are changed. This refresh is basically an AJAX call.
Since this is all builtin, you can very simply use the native feature of binding an event handler to the "after refresh" of this item. There is no need to start listening to dom events. "After refresh" is the standard way of dealing with this.

Two options:

- use a dynamic action which reacts to the "After Refresh" event
  [image: dynamic action creation with after refresh]
- bind to the "apexafterrefresh" event with an eventlistener or jQuery

  ```
  $("#P1_SELECT_LIST").on("apexafterrefresh", function(){ ... });
  ```

From there on you can do anything else you'd like, but this is certainly the way to go.

Comment: As simple it is. Did not see the wood because of the trees... Thanks a lot, that's way more maintainable

Comment: @nik The dom-tree change event listener is cool, just not really in place for this. Also, keep in mind the browsers you need to support. If you roll with that anyway keep in mind it has issues. Dom tree mutation events are done with, and mutation observer is the future. If you have some "older" browsers to support, ouch.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events